# Qt C++ Несколько диапазонов с разрывом в QSpinBox, QDoubleSpinBox

Tags: c++, qt

Как в **QSpinBox**, **QDoubleSpinBox** задать некоторый множественный диапазон? Примеры как должен работать этот SpinBox, аналогично для DoubleSpinBox: 
**1)** Должен принимать *0*, и значения в диапазоне *100-200*.
**2)** Должен принимать значения в диапазоне от *30* до *50*, *80-100*.
**3)** Должен принимать числа *10*, *20*, *30*, и числа в диапазоне *50-60*.
Сейчас у меня есть реализация только для одного диапазона который принимает SpinBox, код прикрепляю. Как лучше(грамотно) сделать реализацию для диапазона с множеством значений? Буду благодарен минимальным примерам.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "spinboxvalidate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);

SpinBoxIntValidator spinBox;
spinBox.setRange(500,600); // Здесь передать перечень диапазонов
spinBox.setToolTip(QString("Введите значение в диапазоне от %1 до %2").arg(500).arg(600));
spinBox.resize(100,100);
spinBox.show();

return a.exec();
}
```

**spinboxvalidate.h**

```
#ifndef SPINBOXVALIDATE_H
#define SPINBOXVALIDATE_H

 #include <QToolTip>
 #include <QValidator>
 #include <QSpinBox>
 #include <QMouseEvent>
 #include <QStyle>
 #include <QStyleOptionSpinBox>

class SpinBoxIntValidator : public QSpinBox
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
explicit SpinBoxIntValidator(QWidget *parent = 0);

virtual QIntValidator::State validate(QString &str, int &pos) const;

protected:

virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
virtual void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
virtual void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent * event);
};

#endif // SPINBOXVALIDATE_H


#ifndef DOUBLESPINBOXVALIDATE_H
#define DOUBLESPINBOXVALIDATE_H

#include <QToolTip>
#include <QValidator>
#include <QDoubleSpinBox>
#include <QDoubleValidator>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QStyle>
#include <QStyleOptionSpinBox>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QVariant>

class DoubleSpinBoxIntValidator : public QDoubleSpinBox
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
explicit DoubleSpinBoxIntValidator(QWidget *parent = 0) : QDoubleSpinBox(parent)
{
}

virtual QDoubleValidator::State validate(QString &str, int &pos) const;

protected:

virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
virtual void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event);
virtual void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent * event);
};

#endif // DOUBLESPINBOXVALIDATE_H
```

**spinboxvalidate.cpp**

```
#include "spinboxvalidate.h"

SpinBoxIntValidator::SpinBoxIntValidator(QWidget *parent) : QSpinBox(parent)
{

}

 QIntValidator::State SpinBoxIntValidator::validate(QString &str, int &pos) const
{
QIntValidator validator;
validator.setRange(minimum(), maximum());
QIntValidator::State state = validator.validate(str, pos);
if (state == QIntValidator::Invalid)
{
    QToolTip::showText(QCursor::pos(), toolTip());
    return state;
}
else if (state == QIntValidator::Intermediate)
{
    return state;
}
else
{
    return state;
}
}

void SpinBoxIntValidator::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
QStyleOptionSpinBox opt;
this->initStyleOption(&opt);

if (this->style()->subControlRect(QStyle::CC_SpinBox, &opt,
                                  QStyle::SC_SpinBoxUp).contains(event->pos()))
{
    if (this->value() == maximum())
    {
        QToolTip::showText(QCursor::pos(), toolTip());
    }
}
else if (this->style()->subControlRect(QStyle::CC_SpinBox, &opt,
                                       QStyle::SC_SpinBoxDown).contains(event->pos()))
{
    if (this->value() == minimum())
    {
        QToolTip::showText(QCursor::pos(), toolTip());
    }
}

QSpinBox::mousePressEvent(event);
event->accept();
}

void SpinBoxIntValidator::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
QSpinBox::keyPressEvent(event);

if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Up)
{
    if (this->value() == maximum())
    {
        QToolTip::showText(QCursor::pos(), toolTip());
    }
}
else if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Down)
{
    if (this->value() == minimum())
    {
        QToolTip::showText(QCursor::pos(), toolTip());
    }
}
}

void SpinBoxIntValidator::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent * event)
{
const int steps = (event->delta() > 0 ? 1 : -1);

if ((steps == -1 && this->value() == minimum()) || (steps == 1 && this->value() == maximum()))
{
    QToolTip::showText(QCursor::pos(), toolTip());
}
else if (stepEnabled() & (steps > 0 ? StepUpEnabled : StepDownEnabled))
{
    stepBy(event->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier ? steps * 10 : steps);
}

event->accept();
}


QDoubleValidator::State DoubleSpinBoxIntValidator::validate(QString &str, int &pos) const
{
QDoubleValidator validator(NULL);
validator.setNotation(QDoubleValidator::StandardNotation);
validator.setRange(minimum(),maximum(), 2);
QDoubleValidator::State state = validator.validate(str, pos);
if (state == QDoubleValidator::Invalid)
{
    QToolTip::showText(QCursor::pos(), toolTip());
    return state;
}
else if (state == QDoubleValidator::Acceptable)
{
    return state;
}

if (state == QDoubleValidator::Intermediate && (str.toDouble() > maximum()) || (str.toDouble() < minimum() && pos > 1))
{ 
    QToolTip::showText(QCursor::pos(), toolTip());
    return QValidator::Invalid;
}
else
{
    return state;
}
}

void DoubleSpinBoxIntValidator::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
QStyleOptionSpinBox opt;
this->initStyleOption(&opt);

if (this->style()->subControlRect(QStyle::CC_SpinBox, &opt,
                                  QStyle::SC_SpinBoxUp).contains(event->pos()))
{
    if (this->value() == maximum())
    {
        QToolTip::showText(QCursor::pos(), toolTip());
    }
}
else if (this->style()->subControlRect(QStyle::CC_SpinBox, &opt,
                                       QStyle::SC_SpinBoxDown).contains(event->pos()))
{
    if (this->value() == minimum())
    {
        QToolTip::showText(QCursor::pos(), toolTip());
    }
}

QDoubleSpinBox::mousePressEvent(event);
event->accept();
}

void DoubleSpinBoxIntValidator::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
QDoubleSpinBox::keyPressEvent(event);

if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Up)
{
    if (this->value() == maximum())
    {
        QToolTip::showText(QCursor::pos(), toolTip());
    }
}
else if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Down)
{
    if (this->value() == minimum())
    {
        QToolTip::showText(QCursor::pos(), toolTip());
    }
}
}

void DoubleSpinBoxIntValidator::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent * event)
{
const int steps = (event->delta() > 0 ? 1 : -1);

if ((steps == -1 && this->value() == minimum()) || (steps == 1 && this->value() == maximum()))
{
    QToolTip::showText(QCursor::pos(), toolTip());
}
else if (stepEnabled() & (steps > 0 ? StepUpEnabled : StepDownEnabled))
{
    stepBy(event->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier ? steps * 10 : steps);
}

event->accept();
}
```

Comment: нум... перегружай `fixUp ()`, `validate ()` и `stepUp ()` и реализуй свою логику... из коробки Qt'шный `spinBox` не умеет работать с несколькими зопами...